# Doppler shift and relative velocity

Tags: doppler-effect

I have come across Doppler shift equation. If we consider the source to be moving toward the observer at a speed $V$ and observer moving toward the source with a speed $U$, for the calculation of the apparent frequency, can't we think of the observer to be at rest from his frame and think that the source is moving with a speed $V+U$?

I have tried to solve a problem doing this but the answers i get are different.

Comment: For what kind of signals?  If there is a physical medium, then the situations are not symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, assuming you are talking about sound waves, you can't add the velocities of the source and the observer in the equation for effective frequency:
$$f_{\text{eff}}=\frac{v'}{\lambda'} $$

The reason is that a source moving toward the observer raises the frequency heard by the observer by decreasing the wavelength of the sound in the denominator (because it is "chasing" its own wave),
$$\lambda'=\frac{(v_{\text{sound}}-{V})}{f},$$
but an observer moving toward the source increases the frequency heard by increasing the relative velocity between him and the sound wave in the numerator.
$$v'=v_{\text{sound}}-U $$
(where $U$ is negative when toward the source).

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, however when you write apparent frequency w.r.t the observer, the apparent frequency of the sound will also change!

[Doppler effect wrt observer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML4g7.jpg)!
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5giP1.jpg)
Thus if you take that into account it will
 match with the original method.
//Note my sense of direction is different