# What is the difference between observer moving and source moving in affecting the sound signal?

Tags: acoustics, inertial-frames, observers, doppler-effect

Why can't we solve all the doppler effect problems for sound in frame of source instead of observer moving using relative velocity.

I want to know why this method does not work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doppler Effect formulas for stationary observer and source](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/665681/)

Comment: Or [In doppler effect derivation why are the considerations for source moving different from that of observer moving?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/665035/179151)

Comment: Or [Doppler shift and relative velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/298869/179151)

Comment: One thing that helped me visualize how doppler effect works are the GIFs at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect , have a look at them, maybe they help you as well. But the short answer is, when a certain wavefront is emitted, it no longer cares about whether the source was moving or stationary. The wavefront is a circle centred at the point where it was emitted, in the frame of the air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let a source $S$ of sound emit waves at frequency $\nu_0$ and a detector $D$
approach it with a uniform velocity $\vec{v}$. If $D$ were still, it would
see the compressions of the wave pass by with a speed $c_s$. However, because
it is approaching the source with a velocity $v$, it sees compressions passing
by with speed $c_s + v$. The wavelength of the wave is seen to be unchanged.
Therefore, the apparent frequency is
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\nu = \frac{c_s + v}{\lambda} = \frac{c_s}{\lambda}
\left(1 + \frac{v}{c_s}\right).
\end{equation}
Now, $c_s/\lambda = \nu_0$ so that
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\nu = \nu_0\left(1 + \frac{v}{c_s}\right).
\end{equation}

Now consider the situation when the detector is stationary but the source
approaches it with a uniform velocity $\vec{v}$. If $S$ were still the detector
will notice a compression every $\lambda$ m apart. However, because $S$ is
approaching $D$ with a speed $v$ the distance is reduced by $v/\nu_0$. The
apparent wavelength is
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\lambda = \lambda_0 - \frac{v}{\nu_0} = \frac{c_s}{\nu_0} - \frac{v}{\nu_0}.
\end{equation}
Since $\lambda = c_s/\nu$, $\nu$ being the apparent frequency, we have
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\nu = \frac{\nu_0}{1 - v/c_s}.
\end{equation}

The formulae for the cases (i) source is stationary and the detector is in
motion and (ii) the other way round, are not symmetric. There are three velocities involved
in the equations, all of them measured with respect to the medium through
which sound waves travel. In the case of equation (1) and (2), $c_s + v$
is the relative velocity of the sound waves with respect to $D$. It is $c_s
-v$ in case of (3) and (4). If we call $c_{sD}$ the relative velocity
in either case, equations (2) and (4) becomes
\begin{eqnarray}
\nu &=& \nu_0\frac{c_{sD}}{c_s} \\
\nu &=& \nu_0\frac{c_s}{c_{sD}}
\end{eqnarray}
In either cases, the numerator is the speed of sound with respect to the moving
body and the denominator is the speed of sound with respect to the medium.

Comment: Elegantly explained

Answer (score 0):

All that matters is who is moving relative to the air (which incidentally is also usually who's moving relative to the ground). That will always be what "breaks the symmetry" of the two reference frames.